# Either WebView or another View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am new to iOS development and also have a mentor, that helps me most of the time, but he isn't available at the moment.

So I am planning on doing an app from a JSON feed (easiest app idea I could come up with). But the page the JSON feed is about supports posts that either have an url or a comment (also the attributes in the JSON file). So if a comment is available, the post doesn't contain a url. But also the other way 'round: If a post contains a url, there is no comment in it.

What I want to do now is checking if the current post that is clicked on the UITableView has a comment or a url and then switching to the WebView or to a normal View.

How to do this one? Because I connected the UITableView with the View where the comment is displayed through Storyboard.

My current prepareForSegue looks like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *story = stories[indexPath.row];

        NSNumber *storyId = story[@"id"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:storyId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a datasource for your table view and then in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method check if your post has a URL or comment.  Based on which one it is you can create the correct view and add that view to the UITableViewCell's contentView.

Something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Create your cell

UIView* contentView = nil;
if (<isURLPost>)
{
    contentView = <CreateAndSetUpYourWebView>;
}
else
{
    contentView = <CreateAndSetUpYourOtherView>;
}

[cell.contentView addSubView:contentView];

}
```